# Border radius não funciona dentro de uma classe CSS

Tags: css, css3

Estou tentando arredondar as bordas de uma barra de navegação através de uma classe e não funciona.

https://jsfiddle.net/oqkt1z9f/

Eu marquei um elemento `<ul>` com a classe `navbar`, removi o padding, a margem e mudei o peso da fonte, mesmo assim as bordas não pegam:

```
.navbar{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

Tem hora que enche o saco, parece que é de um jeito mas é de outro no CSS hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve aplicar o `border-radius` no `li`.

Mas apenas no primeiro (`.navbar li:first-of-type`) e no último (`.navbar li:last-of-type`).

Veja o FIDDLE atualizado e funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/oqkt1z9f/1/

Execute o trecho de código abaixo e veja funcionando:

```css
.navbar{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.navbar li{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#1A1A1A; 
  
}

.navbar li:first-of-type{
  border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.navbar li:last-of-type{
  border-radius:0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.navbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#E8142D
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa seria usar `inline-block` em vez de `float` (se a barra tiver largura total é até melhor). Veja um exemplo:

```css
.navbar{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#1A1A1A;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.navbar li,.navbar a {
  display:inline-block;
}

.navbar a {
  padding:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#E8142D;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/*      daqui pra baixo nem precisa, é só para
     demonstrar como fazer diversas configurações    */

.right {text-align:right}
.short {display:inline-block;text-wrap:none}
.navbar a:hover { color:#000; background:#666; }
ul.navbar {margin-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar right">
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar short">
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>
```

Pontos de interesse:

- Mudamos o padding para dentro do `a`, senão o usuário tem que acertar o clique na parte escrita, Assim, o clique fica no "botão" inteiro da barra
- outras configurações troquei para seus devidos lugares também, assim a lógica do CSS fica mais organizada de acordo com a função dos elementos
- trocamos a cor de fundo para o elemento superior, para podermos aplicar a borda arredondada no `ul`
- usamos `overflow:hidden`, para que o `:hover` não fique com cantos quadrados
- acrescentei um exemplo de `:hover` para você entender a vantagem do `padding` diretamente no link.

Como mencionado pelo @Guilherme, se quiser evitar espaços entre os *inline blocks*, aqui tem vários exemplos de como evitar:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/916193

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que o background esta em elementos dentro do UL e não no UL e estes elementos estão flutuando a direita.

Acho que pelo efeito da imagem você quer que o background se limite a área dos links, então você pode fazer de duas maneiras, usando `display: inline-block;` com `overflow: hidden;` (semelhante ao do @Bacco):

> Em ambos exemplo eu movi o background para o ul

```css
.navbar{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:#1A1A1A; 
}

.navbar li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#E8142D
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>
```

Todavia os elementos do tipo inline ou com `display: inline-*` costumam gerar uma pequena margem abaixo dos elementos (nem sempre, depende da situação e ou uso da font), isto pode ser um pouco chato de resolver, então você pode usar `float` no `ul` e um pseudo-elemento (`::after` ou `:after` para navegadores mais antigos) com `clear:both;`

```css
.navbar{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:5px;
  float:left;
  background-color:#1A1A1A; 
}

.navbar::after, .navbar:after{
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}

.navbar li{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#E8142D
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
</ul>

<div style="background: #fc0;">oi</div>
```

Conversei com o @Bacco, acho que duas soluções que podem ser aplicadas para resolver o espaçamento no `inline-block` seria o `font-size:0` (fora os exemplos que o bacco citou) e criar um elemento pai, desta maneira ele não irá gerar o espaço extra e não ficará grudado na lateral de outro elemnento, por exemplo:

```css
.navbar {
     font-size: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  font-size: 10pt; /*ou font-size: initial;*/
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:#1A1A1A; 
}

.navbar li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#E8142D
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="background: #fc0;">oi</div>
```

E com o float ficaria assim:

```css
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius:5px;
  float:left;
  background-color:#1A1A1A; 
}

.navbar::after, .navbar:after, /*aplica quebra no para o element pai*/
.navbar ul::after, .navbar ul:after { /*aplica quebra no para o UL*/
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}

.navbar li{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  
}
.navbar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#E8142D
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="#artigos">Artigos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="background: #fc0;">oi</div>
```

Comment: Escolhi a resposta do Allan Andrade. As outras duas têm bastante informação e algumas tags do CSS que ainda não entendo direito como funciona como `clear` e `inline-block`.

Mesmo assim daqui alguns dias posso precisar dessas respostas como referência.